# Rescale column values to sum exactly 100

Tags: r, data-transformation

Let's say I have a dataset with 4 columns: country, election year, party name, vote share.

| country | party name | election year | vote share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | CON | 2017 | 42.4 |
| UK | LAB | 2017 | 40.0 |
| UK | CON | 2019 | 43.6 |
| UK | LAB | 2019 | 32.1 |
| ES | PSOE | 2016 | 22.6 |
| ES | PP | 2016 | 33.0 |
| ES | Cs | 2016 | 13.1 |
| ES | PSOE | 2019 | 28.7 |
| ES | PP | 2019 | 16.7 |
| ES | Cs | 2019 | 15.9 |

I am trying to figure out how to create (in R) a new column, named "rescale vote share" in which vote shares of parties in each election will sum up exactly to 100.

For example, in 2017 UK elections, I have data for two parties (CON and LAB). The sum of their vote shares is 42.4 + 40.0 = 82.4. In the new column, I want these two values to add up to 100 while they proportionally retain their difference. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the ratios, divide by the number to which the values sum, then multiply by $100$. Then the rescaled numbers add up to $100$, but since each is multiplied by the same scaling factor, the ratios are unchanged.

$$42.4+40=82.4$$

$$\dfrac{100}{82.4}(42.4+40)= \dfrac{100}{82.4}82.4$$

$$51.5+ 48.5=100$$

However...

$$\dfrac{42.4}{40}=1.06$$

$$\dfrac{51.5}{48.5}\approx 1.06$$

When you carry more digits, the ratio will be a closer approximation to the original $1.06$.

**OLD**

You miss $100$ by $17.6$. Add half of that value to each of your observations, resulting in $51.2$ and $48.8$. This preserves the difference between the two numbers.

If you had three numbers, you’d add $17.6/3$ to each of them. If you had four numbers...

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not adequate. I want the difference between the values to be proportionally the same, not exactly the same. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: So you want to maintain the ratio?

Comment: Yes. I want their values to proportionally increase.